# How to I display a figure using graph-tool without the program blocking?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am trying to write a program which dynamically updates a graph visualization as the state of the graph changes. Currently, the graph_draw method in graph-tool causes the program to halt until the window is closed. Using graph-tool, how can I display the figure and resume execution immediately?

Below is my current call to graph_draw:

```
graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, vertex_font_size=18,
output_size=(200, 200), vertex_fill_color = color_map)
```

I want this to not pause the program until the window has been manually closed.

Currently this pauses the program until the window has been manually closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
graph_draw(g, main=False)
```

in an interactive IPython session.